# How to set id for the views in RemoteViews (appwidget) programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, android-widget

I generate dates for the month calendar inside appwidget, using the code fragment below:

```
    for (week in 0 until 6) {
    val rowRv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.w_calendar_row_week_wrapper)
    
    for (day in 0..6) {
    
    ...
    
    // Set date into cell
    // I need to distinguish textviews later - to choose the date by the click
        dateTextCellRv.setTextViewText(
            android.R.id.text1,
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()
            )
        
    // For click on the chosen date
    val getDateNumber = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString().toInt()
    val clickOnChosenDate: PendingIntent =
        Intent(context, WidgetCalendarProvider::class.java).let { intent ->
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
                intent.putExtra("passedDate$appWidgetId", getDateNumber)
                intent.action = ACTION_CHOSEN_DATE_CLICK_CALENDAR
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context,
                        appWidgetId,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                        )
                    }
    dateTextCellRv.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                android.R.id.text1,
                clickOnChosenDate
                )

    rowRv.addView(R.id.row_week_wrapper_w_calendar, cellRv)
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)           
    }
    rViews.addView(R.id.calendar_view_w_calendar, rowRv)
}
```

**How to set id for all the textviews with dates programmatically?**

**Is it possible to distinguish textviews with android.R.id.text1 for getting string values from each of them by click on any TextView?**